# TypeScript: mixed behaviour for function with multiple parameters of same generic type

Tags: typescript, generics

Given a function which receives two parameters of the same generic type:

```
declare const fn: <T>(t1: T, t2: T) => any;
```

I am trying to reason about the different behaviour TypeScript has when this function is invoked.

When the 2 parameters are *both different primitives*:

```
fn(1, 'foo'); // Error due to different types
```

When the 2 parameters are *both different objects*:

```
fn({ foo: 1 }, { bar: 1 }) // No error and return type is union of different types
```

How come these two usages don't have the same behaviour? I would expect them both to behave the same. Either:

- Error due to different types
- No error and return type is union of different types

Secondly, TypeScript's behaviour is different again if one of the parameters passed in is a variable (rather than an inline object literal):

```
fn({ foo: 1 }, { bar: 1 }) // No error and return type is union of different types

const obj = { foo: 1 };
fn(obj, { bar: 1 }) // Error due to different types
```

Again, how come these two usages don't have the same behaviour? I would expect both of these cases to behave the same.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19252

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18734

Comment: The problem is probably related to how inference works in TypeScript. It's happy to infer a union of two objects, because the inferred type of objects is as if they're polymorphic in "the rest of" the properties, instead of being closed, whereas `1` and `'foo'` are not polymorphic. There's an issue somewhere about "closed" object types, so that `{ foo: "bar", baz: "quux" }` is an inadmissible `{ | foo: "bar" | }`. If the inferred type of object literals was then `{ | ... | }` instead of `{ ... }`, you wouldn't run into this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/19513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compelling use case for this behavior comes from examples like this, where you have some candidate set of types, none is a supertype of the others, but the intended inferred type parameter (`{ a?: number, b?: number, c?: number }`) is pretty obvious:

```
declare const fn: <T>(t1: T, t2: T, t3: T) => any;

fn({ a: 0, b: 1 }, { b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 4, c: 5 });
```

Why does this not happen when the arguments aren't object literals?

When you have some *binding* `foo` with some type `T`, TypeScript can't* know that the object pointed to by `foo` has *exactly* the type `T` - it might have *more* properties that weren't declared in `T`, but ended up bound to `foo` via a subtype relation. This is very common in practice.

For this reason, in the example in the OP, inferring the type `{ foo?: number, bar?: number }` would be unsound because `obj` might have pointed to an object with a `bar` property of type `string`.

`*` You could add more special cases around `const`s which were initialized with an object literal that wasn't type-asserted to something else, but that would just make things even more inconsistent

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! That makes sense. How about the first part of my question (primitives vs objects)? I'm not sure you covered that, unless I'm missing something? Or perhaps that answer can be found in the PR you linked to in your comment (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/19513)?

Comment: The primitive behavior and the non-fresh-object behavior are the same; it's only fresh objects which receive special treatment